# Accessing data on distributed database on OrientDB

Tags: database, amazon-ec2, distributed-computing, orientdb, distributed-database

I'm new to distributed databases. I configured a distributed OrientDB configuration on multiple EC2 instances and they recognize each other and are communicating with each other.

1) Now, suppose I have a particular database on server 1 and not on server 2. If I set autoDeployment=false, server 2 only downloads a distributed config for the said database on server 2 and not the entire database. If I query server 2 for data from the database, it says it does not have access to the database. Is there a way to configure such that my OrientDB DBMS can find out where the data is in the distributed database and I can ping one server and get whatever data I need? If yes, I can't seem to find documentation on how to do this.

2) Is there a way I can set a replication count to the number of copies I want to maintain, in a 4 node cluster? i.e Suppose I insert a document into server 1 and want one more copy of the data on any of the other 3 nodes. How do i set this up?